# How to retrieve JSON values from an AJAX POST in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, http-post

None of the other questions around this topic have helped me.

I'm posting some Json via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/promotions/productprice/saveorupdate",
    data: JSON.stringify({
            ProductPriceID: 50,
            ProductID: 50,
            PromotionPrice: 0.0,
            SiteID: 0,
            Deleted: 0,
            ProductPriceTypeID: 0,
            StartDate: "",
            EndDate: "",
            ParentSiteID: 0}),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

To this method:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> SaveOrUpdate([FromBody] ProductPrice productPrice)
    {
        return Json("");
    }
```

And my model is defined as such:

```
public class ProductPrice
{
    public int ProductPriceID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public decimal? PromotionPrice { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public int Deleted { get; set; }
    public int ProductPriceTypeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public int? ParentSiteID { get; set; }
}
```

Using the network tab in Chrome I can see the request is sending with the payload:

[image]

But why is the value in C# always null?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use the following code:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/promotions/productprice/saveorupdate",
    data: {
            ProductPriceID: 50,
            ProductID: 50,
            PromotionPrice: "1.2",
            SiteID: 0,
            Deleted: 0,
            ProductPriceTypeID: 0,
            StartDate: "",
            EndDate: "",
            ParentSiteID: 0                   
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    /*contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'  */               
});
```

Remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` to use the default value. The default is: [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Parameters are bound using the request headers. Therefore, remove the `[FromBody]` attribute. The `[FromHeader]` will be used by default.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveOrUpdate(ProductPrice productPrice)
{
    ...
   return Json("Ok");
}
```

*NOTE: In your case don't use the `JSON.stringify()` function, because of you will receive a string on the controller side and then you need to use the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize()` to get your object as  `ProductPrice` type.*

[image]